# How can I configure bundler to never overwrite certain bin files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Whenever I run `bundle [install]`, bundler overwrites the non-standard rails "rails" and "rack" binstubs with its standard ones, and I have to reset them.

Is there a way to tell bundler to ignore these files, but to normal behavior with the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way to give Bundler a list of binstubs to exclude. The current recommendation is *not* to use `bundle install --binstubs` to automatically generate binstubs for all of your executables, but instead to use `bundle binstubs <command>` to generate the ones that you need.

If you have ever run `bundle install --binstubs` in the past, it will remember that and re-generate them every time you run `bundle install`, so you need to take two steps:

1. Remove the remembered setting by editing `.bundle/config` in your project directory and remove the `BUNDLE_BIN` line.
2. Create the binstubs that you actually want with `bundle binstubs rspec` (as an example).

Comment: "Create the binstubs that you actually want" ... but i love all my children equally...

Comment: Keep in mind that you only need to create each binstub once. You don't need to regenerate them every time you run Bundle install. :)